# Application Wrapper must end in .app. for submitting my app

Tags: xcode, ios5, app-store

This is the message that appears when i try to upload my .zip file by the way I am using Application Loader which I believe is integrated with Xcode

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, just choose Archive from the Product menu, then the Organizer will open to reveal the build once it's done compiling. Then click Submit.